# Upper Case Everything Before the nth character in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, comparison

I need to capitalize everything before the second - from the beginning of the string in .NET.  What is the best way to do this?  The string before the second dash can be anything. I need a new single string once this is complete.

Before

```
Tt-Fga - Louisville - Kentucky
```

After

```
TT-FGA - Louisville - Kentucky
```

Comment: split on the hyphens, .ToUpper() on the first two elements of the array? Not sure if this is too basic? Do you need a fancy way to do this?

Comment: IndexOf twice to find the second hyphen, then Substring(first part).ToUpper + Substring(second part)

Comment: Split String By - and Store it into array. After it Use ToUpper() for first two Elements of Array....

Comment: Love the downvotes with no reason

Comment: This is a legitimate "best way" style question.

Comment: Downvoted because "this question does not show any research effort"

Comment: Why do I need a research effort? I want the best way possible to do this.  I didnt have anything working until I posted this.

Comment: maybe if you had provided something against which to do a benchmark?

Comment: This is ridiculous. @MikeFlynn asked a basic "best way" question. He probably thought through the algorithm a bit in his head first. He isn't some user with 10 rep, he has 5k and I think he can be given the benefit of the doubt that he considered some options before looking for the masses to give their own input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and did this.  If there is a better answer let me know.

```
 var parts = @event.EventParent.Name.Split(new[] {'-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i >= 2)
                            break;

                        parts[i] = parts[i].ToUpper();
                    }
                    @event.EventParent.Name = string.Join("-", parts);
```

Comment: Splitting will unnecessarily construct a new array and extra strings, which then must be joined back together. Using `IndexOf` is much more efficient.

Comment: At the very least, use the overload for `Split` that specifies a maximum number of elements, so that you can limit it to 3 pieces.

Comment: What you've tried should be in your question. That way you won't attract negatives on your question because you've apparently attempted nothing and negatives on your answer because it's not great.

Comment: `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` seems wrong here. `a--b` has only `a-` before the second dash, so according to your question, should be changed to `A--b`. Unless I'm misreading, your answer gives `A-B`, uppercasing too much, and removing a `-`.

Comment: There will never be a `--`

Answer (score 3):

This should get the job done for your specific case:

```
public static string ToUpperUntilSecondHyphen(string text)
{
    int index = text.IndexOf('-', text.IndexOf('-') + 1);
    return text.Substring(0, index).ToUpper() + text.Substring(index);
}
```

A more generalized method could look something like this:

```
public static string ToUpperUntilNthOccurrenceOfChar(string text, char c, int occurrences)
{
    if (occurrences > text.Count(x => x == c))
    {
        return text.ToUpper();
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < occurrences; i++, index++)
    {
        index = text.IndexOf(c, index);
    }
    return text.Substring(0, index).ToUpper() + text.Substring(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Identify the location of the hyphen with `IndexOf`. You'll have to use this function twice so that you can find the first hyphen, and then the second one.
2. Construct the substring that only contains the characters up to that with `Substring`. Construct the substring that contains all the remaining characters as well.
3. Upper case the first string with `ToUpper`.
4. Concatenate with the + operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?-.*)(?=-)
```

You can use replace here.Replace with `$1.upper()` or something which is available in `c#`.

See

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/50

Comment: Don't you think regex is a bit heavy for such a simple job? It will undoubtedly be much slower.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer it will be slower but the question is tagged regex,so why cant we show OP the various choices and let him pick the best?